# Why $H_{dR}^1(M) \simeq \mathbb R^n$ when $H_1(M,\mathbb Z)$ has $n$ generators?

Tags: homology-cohomology, hodge-theory, de-rham-cohomology

Let $M$ be compact, connected and orientable manifold without boundary. Let $\sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_n$ be generators of $H_1(M,\mathbb Z)$. Why is the map $I:H_{dR}^1(M) \to \mathbb R^n$ given by
$$I([a]) = \left(\int_{\sigma_1} a , \ldots, \int_{\sigma_n} a\right)$$
an isomorphism?

I believe the proof involves Hodge theorem but I do not know where.

Observation: $H_{dR}^1(M)$ is the first De Rham cohomology group and $H_1(M,\mathbb Z)$ is the first singular homology group with coefficients on $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: This is not true in the presence of torsion: Consider $\mathbb{RP^2}$.

Comment: Ah ok, I forgot to add that $M$ is orientable.

Comment: This is also false on $RP^3$ I think.